# Hide Document When UserForm Initializes without affecting other unrelated documents but also keep a taskbar icon

Tags: vba, ms-word, hide, userform

I want to initialize a form upon running a document.

In a module I entered the following Code:

```
Public Sub AutoOpen()
    UserFormLaunchWindow.Show
End Sub
```

Which sends to command to show the UserForm.

The UserForm has the following Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ActiveDocument.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisDocument.Windows(1).Visible = True
If Not Application.Documents.Count > 1 Then
    ThisDocument.Save
    Application.Quit
Else
    ThisDocument.Save
    ActiveDocument.Close True 'Here if I use ThisDocument, all docs open close.
End If
End Sub
```

Which is supposed to make the Document Invisible and keep just the UserForm Window displayed.

However, during the initialization of the userform if there is another instance of word open for another unrelated document it closes it too, or hides it too, not sure which.

The ultimate goal is to open the initialized Userform, Hide only the Document that initializes the UserForm without affecting any other documents. Keep a taskbar icon to easily show the UserForm. Also when closing the UserForm, it shouldn't affect any other unrelated documents.

Comment: First, test whether more than one document is open. If more than one, Instead of using the generic ActiveDocument and ThisDocument, you'll have to get the document name or index, then refer to the document using that. i.e. Documents("DocumentName").Windows(1).Visible = True

Comment: I used:        Documents("Under Construction.docm").Windows(1).Visible = False    and it has the same effect.  If I have Document1 already open, running "Under Construction.docm" closes and or hides Document1 too.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not running this code from an add-in/global template? Then no document is generated and nothing has to be hidden. https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/what_templates_define_and__store.html

Comment: The computers at work and for my workers are all managed and limited to what can be installed.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of reading, but it's all past my knowledge. I checked out this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/67425818/11445221 created by - @macropod. And This code https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/close-word-document-within-excel-vba.995671/post-4777788 created by him too. Does anyone think sections of that code may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why your code resulting that situation, the same code I used to test is OK . When the Form opens, just the .docm Document will be hidden, and when it closes also only the .docm document file closes.

the code in the **UserForm** whose name is "UserFormLaunchWindow"

```vb
Option Explicit

Rem cocode with chatGPT

Rem If your Office is 64-bit, you must add PtrSafe before the "Function" and after the word "Declare"。
Rem Unfortunately, the topmost display in the 64-bit Office run seems to be invalid. So chatGPT taught me to do this:

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ThisDocument.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    topMostTerminate
    UserFormTerminate
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    topMost
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    topMostTerminate
End Sub

Private Sub topMost()
    ' Set UserForm to always be displayed at the top ( topmost)
    'SetWindowPos Me.hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
    SetWindowPos ThisDocument.Windows(1).hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
End Sub

Private Sub topMostTerminate()
    ' When closing UserForm, return the focus to the main window of the Word application
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hwndWord As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hwndWord As Long
    #End If
    hwndWord = FindWindow("OpusApp", Application.Caption)
    SetWindowPos hwndWord, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
End Sub

Private Sub UserFormTerminate()
    Rem The document will eventually be closed, there is no need to show it again.
    'ThisDocument.Windows(1).Visible = True
    If Not Application.Documents.Count > 1 Then
        ThisDocument.Save
        Word.Application.Quit
    Else
        If Not ThisDocument.Saved Then ThisDocument.Save
        ThisDocument.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

the code in **ThisDocument** object in the .docm file where saves both the code and the form

```vb
Private Sub Document_Open()

    UserFormLaunchWindow.Show False

End Sub
```

**remark:**

If you want to open this userform code document file without executing the program, you can hold down "**Shift**" key and open the file. For example, when you want to edit or check the code.

[sample file, download and check it out](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tIjeomewV2DXmBUyXS1ULMTb7yT9IeuO/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106108182093734588005&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I did test the code identically as you provided it.  I tested it at work and at home.  Unfortunately, if I have other documents open it always closes one of them.  Example.  I open three blank word documents and then I run the file in question, one of the three blank documents will close leaving just two.  If I close the file and do it again, another will be closed and leave one left.  if I do it a third time the last blank document will be closed.  All this happens at launch only.

Comment: @RaudelJr I did open three new and blank documents, and try to figure out , but there is not any one that will be affected like what you describe, and it works normally and well. If you only have the code I posted, then it is very strange. The problem should be with another add-in or template program that is running and you don't see it. Or you could put a breakpoint in the appropriate place and press Ctrl + L to check the stack to see what program triggered the action to close the other file. Or run your form-starting or form-closing procedures line by line to find out where the problem lies.

Comment: because of the continued issues I created a New Blank form.  I did nothing to it but only saved it as Doc1.docm.  Then I opened a brand new Blank form not saved, just new doc automatically named by word as Document1 and left it like that.  Then I opened the Doc1.docm file I saved containing no code at all, just saved as docm.  When opening it closed the unsaved bland Document1.  Obviously this is a different issue.  So I did it all over again, but on the new Document1 I entered a single character letter.  Then I opened the Doc1.docm file and it didn't close the Document1.

Comment: It seems that *.docm files close the completely blank and unsaved opened files.  Sorry for the back and forth.  This has turned into a whole other issue aside from my original request.  Your Code works perfect and doesn't affect anything else when the opened documents are saved, or when an unsaved open document is not completely blank.  I wonder if this is an issue on my end with my word/office setting/options.

Comment: @RaudelJr What I know is that when a blank file is opened for the first time, if no changes are made, then the first blank file will be closed automatically when opening a saved file. This is the MS Word default, is normal. But the second and subsequent blank files will not be closed directly like the first one, but normally they will be left. It does not matter if it is a .docm file or not. And you have said that your own computer and your company's computer both will do the same thing, which is really unbelievable. Did you install it with the same installer?

Comment: @OscarSunAt work our computers are managed by a third party and we are unable to install programs.  At home my office I installed myself several years back.  I'm glad you mentioned this is a default behavior for MS Word.  It's true that it only happens to the first blank file and it does not affect subsequent blank files.  I thank you for your help with this.  Your code works perfectly fine. But once the document is hidden the UserForm left visible has no taskbar icon.  So once it's hidden behind other windows, those windows need to be minimized in order to locate the UserForm window.

Comment: is there a way to code it so that the UserForm has a taskbar icon?

Comment: @RaudelJr I regret that since this UserForm is built into the MS Word application and does not work independently, at best it can only display icons from the document itself and not from the form icons within the document. In Word VBA, it may not be feasible to display icons directly in the taskbar. After all, Word VBA has limited support for customizing taskbar icons.

Comment: @RaudelJr Typically, user forms in Word VBA do not have the ability to display icons in the taskbar or system tray as other applications do. You may want to consider using another programming language or development environment to implement this feature, such as using C#, or VB.
In Word VBA, user forms are typically used to display and collect data, rather than being used as a standalone application running in the taskbar or system tray.

Comment: @RaudelJr If you want the form to run without being obscured by other documents, then you can remove the "False" argument I gave in the Show method, which by default is opened exclusively (modally) so that it will not be obscured by other Word documents. Unless you open another Word instance, it is possible that it will be obscured. 
Even so, I made the form the top form in the operating system so that not only would Word not cover it, but other windows would not cover it either. Do you think it works for you? Check out the code I've just updated. Good luck!

Comment: @RaudelJr This is the [file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tIjeomewV2DXmBUyXS1ULMTb7yT9IeuO/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106108182093734588005&rtpof=true&sd=true) I test. You can download it to test by yourself, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253714/discussion-between-oscar-sun-and-raudeljr).

Comment: Thank you. I will test the file at work and will let you know. I consider this thread answered. I really appreciate your help. Will continue contact via chat as requested. Thanks again. 